# Me aparecen WARNINGS al INSERTAR en una tabla con PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Buenos días, al momento de insertar en un formulario con PHP si inserta los registros en la base de datos pero me lanza los siguientes WARNINGS:

> Warning: Variable parameter 1 not passed by reference (prefaced with
>   an &). Variable parameters passed to sqlsrv_prepare or sqlsrv_query
>   should be passed by reference, not by value. For more information, see
>   sqlsrv_prepare or sqlsrv_query in the API Reference section of the
>   product documentation. in C:\xampp\htdocs\sana_php\registro.php on
>   line 69
>
> Warning: Variable parameter 2 not passed by reference (prefaced with
>   an &). Variable parameters passed to sqlsrv_prepare or sqlsrv_query
>   should be passed by reference, not by value. For more information, see
>   sqlsrv_prepare or sqlsrv_query in the API Reference section of the
>   product documentation. in C:\xampp\htdocs\sana_php\registro.php on
>   line 69
>
> Warning: Variable parameter 3 not passed by reference (prefaced with
>   an &). Variable parameters passed to sqlsrv_prepare or sqlsrv_query
>   should be passed by reference, not by value. For more information, see
>   sqlsrv_prepare or sqlsrv_query in the API Reference section of the
>   product documentation. in C:\xampp\htdocs\sana_php\registro.php on
>   line 69
>
> Warning: Variable parameter 4 not passed by reference (prefaced with
>   an &). Variable parameters passed to sqlsrv_prepare or sqlsrv_query
>   should be passed by reference, not by value. For more information, see
>   sqlsrv_prepare or sqlsrv_query in the API Reference section of the
>   product documentation. in C:\xampp\htdocs\sana_php\registro.php on
>   line 69

El código que utilizo es el siguiente`

```
if ($errores == '') {
            $query=('INSERT INTO t_usuarios(nombre, usuario, correo, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
            $statement=sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, array($nombre, $usuario, $mail, $pass));
            $resultado=sqlsrv_execute($statement);
        }
```

Y los valores que paso son los que se muestran a continuación:

```
$nombre=filter_var(strtolower($_POST['nombre']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$usuario=filter_var(strtolower($_POST['usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
#$usuario='gspindolab';
$mail=strtolower($_POST['mail']);
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$pass2=$_POST['pass2'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que te esta sugiriendo ese warning es que debes enviar las variables en ese arreglo como referencia, leyendo la documentación oficial tu linea de código debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
$statement=sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, array(&$nombre, &$usuario, &$mail, &$pass));
```

Más información en el siguiente link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ec/library/cc296181(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, enseguida leo cual es el motivo por el cual hay que poner eso